# Clustering Large Number of Strings

Tags: python, data-science, hierarchical-clustering

I have a list of ~381,000 strings. I managed to calculate the string distance for all NC2 pairs (~72 billion).

Now, I would like to form clusters of strings for quick search. I usually use sklearn agglomerative clustering. But, I fear this time I might face memory issues.

The purpose of the string cluster is so that I can quickly search similar names when the Data Entry Executive enters a name.

How can I achieve clustering on such a large set? Are there better ways to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Due to the number of datapoints it seems like you'll need some form of streaming algorithm. What is the distance metric that you are using for your agglomerative clustering? If euclidean why not look into a gaussian mixture model clustering where you could use EM as your algorithm. Performing stochastic EM would then allow the streamed data?

Comment: I'm currently using a custom weighted Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been clearer. I am assuming the Levenshtein distance is what you are using to "calculate the string distance"? What do you use in the agglomerative clustering? (The default is affinity='euclidean')

Comment: Sure, I use the default. I'll looking into your suggestion of gaussian mixture model clustering. Thanks for the heads up :).

Comment: So this doesn't mean the gaussian mixture model assumptions are correct but it at least means you don't make additional assumptions about the data than your agglomerative algorithm isn't already doing.

Comment: Have you seen MiniBatchKMeans from scikit-learn? Here is a walkthrough: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html#